# How do I create EcmaScript classes on the fly?

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic, custom-element

If I want to dynamically create new classes (not instances) on the fly in EcmaScript, how can I do this? And how can those instances `extend` from another class?

Traditionally one could make a "class":

```
function Living(){}
Living.prototype.eat = function(){ console.log("eat") }
```

Then **dynamically** extend it:

```
function makeSubclass(name, parentClass){
  var klass = new Function()
  klass.name = name
  klass.displayName = name
  klass.prototype = parentClass.prototype
  klass.prototype.constructor = klass
}
var Animal = makeSubclass("Animal", Living)
var dog = new Animal()
dog.eat() //=> eat
```

And so on:

```
Animal.prototype.walk = function(){ console.log("one foot then another") }
var Person = makeSubclass("Person", Animal)
var rektide = new Person()
rektide.eat() //=> eat
rektide.walk() //=> one foot then another
```

The key is that I wish to do so dynamically, in a data-driven manner. This traditional approach let's me *dynamically* create new classes:

```
fetch("http://yoyodyne.net/animals").then(response => response.json()).then(animals => {
    animals.forEach(animalName => window[animalName] = makeSubclass(animalName, Animal)
})
```

And thus I can dynamically, data-drivenly create the classes I need.

The theory I thought I was told was that EcmaScript classes were just syntax sugar, and that I could keep using old syntax. However we are starting to see examples where only EcmaScript classes will do (such as [Custom Elements](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/587))  and so this ability to on the fly define new classes (as opposed to using a class expression, which is a *static* construction) becomes important.

In the Custom Elements needing new `class` syntax issue, Domenic Denicola writes

> I hope you're aware that you can generate classes dynamically just as easily as functions,

And so I'd like to ask, how? If I want a new class that extends HTMLElement, how can I create that on the fly, in a data-driven manner?

Comment: Note that you can still define custom elements using the 'old' syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_expressions):

```
class Living {
  eat() {
    return 42
  }
}

const livingThings = {}
;['dog', 'cat'].forEach((name) => (
  livingThings[name] = class extends Living {
    name() { return name }
  }
))

const myDog = new livingThings.dog()
myDog.eat()  //=> 42
myDog.name() //=> 'dog'
```

The superclass here (`Living`), can be replaced with anything, as it’s an expression (`Living`, after all, is just like any other variable).

That said, I would try to avoid dynamically creating classes, if possible, and instead use instances.

Comment: Andrew: you have not *dynamically* created a class, you've authored a class expression which can only be done *statically.* If I have a spreadsheet of Living things I want to create subclasses for, class expressions will make me statically type each out.

Comment: @rektide Incorrect (unless “dynamic” means something different to you). See my edit. Your original example didn’t include a loop, so I didn’t in mine. Hopefully it’s clearer now with it.

Comment: @rektide you're confusing class _declarations_ (static) with class _expressions_.

Comment: In the answer's example, Living is a well known class. I'd like to see parity with what JS was capable of before, and what 'makeSubclass' shows, which is dynamically creating subclasses extending a *not-specified-ahead-of-time* class. I did not code that in to my original example, but it's easy enough to pretend that yoyodyne's list of animals includes some taxological chaining- Pheasant is in subfamily Phasianinae in order Galliformes &c.

Comment: @rektide Did you bother to try to put something else instead of `Living`? It’s just an expression like anywhere else, and you could easily replace it with a function call. This is true in class definitions as well.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. I can indeed make a klasses = {...} type thing then do var myvar = class extends klasses["Living"], for example. That satisfies. Thanks. Major FUD-busting exercise getting me here; many thanks.